# Taxes when selling products/services in bitcoin

Tags: taxes

If I sell products/services in bitcoins, do I need to convert them to dollar (or the local currency) always? Or it's ok to charge in Bitcoin and fill the invoice in BTC (and/or with the conversion to local currency) but keep the payment in BTC?

Or we need to always convert them to local currency and leave the registry of that transaction in some bank of our company etc?

// Sorry if it's duplicate because I think this must be a common question but I'm not finding the answers.

Comment: There is no 'correct answer' to this question, it is just a matter of accounting, preference, and perhaps adherence to local regulation/taxation on business practices. If you are concerned about taxes with respect to bitcoin, then you need to talk to an accountant or lawyer that operates in your jurisdiction, not random people on the internet.

Comment: I want to know the different alternatives, I can create the company in any country. Besides that I think is a very general question, most of the countries will probably fit in 3 or 4 different scenarios